# Rails 4 action mailer environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables, actionmailer

I'm creating simple form to email form using actionmailer in a Rails 4 app.

When I use the following settings in my development.rb file everything works fine:

```
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address: "mail.hover.com",
      port: 587,
      domain: "blah.com",
      user_name: "dennis@blah.com",
      password: "thisBeMyPassword",
      authentication: 'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true,
      openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
  }
```

But when I try to use a an ENV variable in my code like so, I get an authentication fails error:

```
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address: "mail.hover.com",
      port: 587,
      domain: "blah.com",
      user_name: "dennis@blah.com",
      password: ENV["MY_EMAIL_PASSWORD"],
      authentication: 'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true,
      openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
  }
```

I can see this variable in the terminal when I use `printenv` in the console and when I stick `puts ENV["MY_EMAIL_PASSWORD"]` in the code.

I've triple-checked spelling, capitalization, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the problem but I can recommend the [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro). It makes it really easy to handle environment variables. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: I just went with this gem and it worked as advertised.